# Keep external monitor connected when computer is locked

Tags: display, sleep-wake, power-management

On my 2016 MBP with an external monitor connected through DisplayPort, when I lock my computer, the monitor is immediately "disconnected", so when I unlock my computer, it takes up to 15 seconds to re-detect the external monitor and re-arrange windows.

Is there anyway I can make lock just be lock, and not a "mini-sleep"? My agenda here is not to conserve power (and I'm on full mains power), but to exercise good information security. It's annoying, and I'm finding myself not locking my computer when stepping away for a short period of time, which is bad INFOSEC.

Comment: When you lock your screen, does your Mac go to sleep as well?

Comment: Not sure, how would I tell? Screen's black (which is the point..), so what else?

Comment: when you lock, you should see your login screen

Comment: Ah, that's probably the issue then -- it doesn't lock, it actually goes to sleep.

Comment: If you click on the Apple Logo , select “Lock Screen” Does that still put the computer to sleep?